# Image.load function is not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new at JavaScript / jQuery.
The below example does call the `.each` part for every waterfall-item in my list. But the `$img.load` is never called for some reason?

Can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var $waterfall = $('.waterfall');
    if ($waterfall.length) {
      $waterfall.waterfall({});
    }

    // sort the waterfall when images are loaded
    var $waterfallItem = $('.waterfall-item');
    $waterfallItem.each(function(j, image) {
      var $img = $(image);

      $img.load(function() {
        $waterfall.waterfall({});
      });
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<ul class="waterfall">
  <li class="waterfall-item">
    <a href="hidden link" title="hidden title">
      <img alt="hidden alt" title="hidden title" data-srcset="hidden in this example" data-src="also hidden in this example" src="still hidden in this example" data-sizes="(min-width:440px) 300px, 95vw" class=" lazyloaded" sizes="(min-width:440px) 300px, 95vw"
      srcset="think I'll hide this one too">
      <span class="waterfallImgOverlay"></span>
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check the reference to load function https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I've seen that page but don't really understand everything or know what I'm looking for exactly.

Comment: Have you tried putting your jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Comment: Oh sry, it is in the document ready function, forgot to add that.

Comment: `var $img = $(image);` this doesn't return the `img` element but the `li` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```js
var $waterfall = $('.waterfall');
if ($waterfall.length) {
  $waterfall.waterfall({});
}

// sort the waterfall when images are loaded
var $waterfall_images = $waterfall.find('img');
$waterfall_images.each(function(j, image) {
  var $img = $(image);

  $img.load(function() {
    $waterfall.waterfall({});
  });


});
```